# Nested attributes. Field doesn't update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes, nested

I have my models like these:

```
class Listicle < ActiveRecord::Base
...
 has_many :listicle_sticker_tags, -> { order(listicle_sticker_id: :asc) }, class_name: 'ListicleStickerTag', dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :listicle_sticker_tags, allow_destroy: true
end


class ListicleStickerTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listicle
  belongs_to :listicle_sticker
end
```

And the controller has:

```
class ListiclesController < ApplicationController

def basic_listicle_params
    params.require(:listicle).permit :item_separator_color, :vote_count_color, :arrows_default_color,
                                     :show_shareaholic, :arrows_on_hover_color, :arrows_selected_color, :items_order,
                                     :show_stickers, :intro, :footer, :show_vote_feedback, :stickers_for_each_item,
                                     on_load_scripts_attributes: [:id, :script, :position, :_destroy],
                                     questions_attributes: [:body, :_destroy, :id],
                                     listicle_sticker_tags_attributes: [:id, :listicle_sticker_id, :text, :_destroy]

....
end
```

And the view:

```
.form-group
  -@listicle.ordered_questions.each do |question,idx|
    =form.label 'ID:'
    = question.id
    =form.label 'Title:'
    = question.body.present? ? question.title : "Item #{idx + 1}"
    - @stickers.each do |sticker|
      = sticker.id
      = sticker.text


      = form.fields_for :listicle_sticker_tags do |u|
        .nested-fields.form-group
          .field

            = link_to_remove_association u, class: %(text-danger pull-right) do
              %i.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove-circle{style:"position: relative; top: 25px; right: 2px; font-size: 18px;"}
            = u.text_area :text, rows:4, class: %w(form-control)
            = u.hidden_field :listicle_sticker_id, :value => sticker.id
      .links
        %br
        =link_to_add_association 'Add script', form, :listicle_sticker_tags, class: %w(btn btn-primary pull-right)
```

The problem is :listicle_sticker_id won't update and is returned as nil.
as you see, it is not even updated:

```
 SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO `listicle_sticker_tags` (`listicle_id`, `text`) VALUES (39, 'hhhhhhhhhhhhhh')
   (4.7ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered listicles/update.js.erb (0.4ms)
```

Console output is as following:

```
2.1.1 :067 > ListicleStickerTag.where(listicle_id: 39)
  ListicleStickerTag Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `listicle_sticker_tags`.* FROM `listicle_sticker_tags`  WHERE `listicle_sticker_tags`.`listicle_id` = 39
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<ListicleStickerTag id: 35, listicle_id: 39, text: "hhhhhhhhhhhhhh", listicle_sticker_id: nil>]>
```

What am I missing to make listicle_sticker_id to be updated on submit?

Comment: What is in the `@stickers` variable? Are they stickers from the database, or are they new, unpersisted records?

Comment: what are the params in log for this request? do they have proper listicle_sticker_id?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the server after modifying strong params helped in my case.